# How to use enum within a struct in ANSI C?

Tags: c, struct, initialization, enums, declaration

Following code has to be used in the main-function, but I don't know how it is used.

```
struct SomeItem
{
    enum {MOVIE, MUSIC} itemType;
    union {
        struct Movie* movie;
        struct Music* music;
    };
};
```

this struct is used in a dynamic linked list with previous/item/next pointer, but I don't know how you can set the enum. Or how to initialize it.

I need to know how it would look like in the main-function.

```
biglist.someitem = ???;
/* declaration I use */
struct Library* biglist;
```

more code to understand what Im trying to do.

```
struct Library{
struct SomeItem* someitem;
struct SomeItem* previousItem;
struct SomeItem* nextItem;
};
```

compiler errors:
C2037: left of 'someitem' specifies undefined struct/union 'library'
C2065: MOVIE: undeclared identifier

Im still a rookie on ANSI C, so dont shoot me ok ;)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `typedef enum` outside the struct declaration?

Comment: So on what code line the compiler actually fails???  http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: For the first error, you're not showing the line that the compiler is complaining about. For the second error, either the definition of `struct` is not visible at that point, or you're trying to build C code with a C++ compiler. Post more of your program, please. It's hard to do psychic debugging.

Comment: I have figured out my error on top of the ones I was already making...
I didnt include the modules properly where those structs where defined.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using pointers everywhere, so you need to use -> to reference the items.

ie.        `biglist->someitem->itemType = MOVIE;`

The below code compiles fine with gcc -Wall -strict:

```
struct SomeItem
{
    enum {MOVIE, MUSIC} itemType;
    union {
        struct Movie* movie;
        struct Music* music;
    } item;
};

struct Library{
   struct SomeItem* someitem;
   struct SomeItem* previousItem;
   struct SomeItem* nextItem;
};

int main(void)
{
   struct Library* biglist;

   biglist->someitem->itemType = MOVIE;

   return 0;
}
```

(Though this code won't run of course, as I'm not allocating any memory for biglist and someitem!)

Comment: You need to name the union in the struct to be useful ?  Like Siddique's answer.

Comment: @user982671 Yes, good point, I've updated that. (For reference, anonymous unions are permitted in gcc and also in ANSI C as of C11.)

Answer (score 4):

```
biglist.someitem.itemType = MOVIE; /* or = MUSIC */
```

Or, if `someitem` is a pointer,

```
biglist.someitem->itemType = MOVIE; /* or = MUSIC */
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler, I have tried to do that, but the program still won't compile. I feel I have to give additional code..

Comment: You should post the code that you are using to attempt to set the value (including declarations for all the variables involved), and the exact error message produced by the compiler. And edit this stuff into your question; don't reply with it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct SomeItem 
{ 
    enum {MOVIE, MUSIC} itemType; 
    union { 
        struct Movie* movie; 
        struct Music* music; 
    } item;
    struct SomeItem *next;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may initialize the enum in such a way biglist->someitem = MOVIE; but the compiler assigns integer values starting from 0. So:
biglist->someitem=MOVIE returns 0  or 
biglist->someitem=MUSIC return 1

check if it helps any good,