# Giving a value to an enum in a struct in C

Tags: c

I have following struct defined in a header file which I cannot edit (not allowed to):

```
struct Programma
{
enum {SERIE, FILM} programmaType;

char* titel;
char* zender;

time_t start;
time_t einde;

char* review;

union 
{
    Serie* serie;
    Film* film;
} typeData;
};
```

I've tried:

```
Programma asd;

asd.programmaType = SERIE; //Error: identifier 'SERIE' is undefined
asd.programmaType = 0; //Error: a value of type 'int'cannot be assigned to an entity of type 'enum PRogramma::<unnamed>
```

and in a function with a pointer to a Programma struct as parameter replacing the '.' by '->', which gave me the same errors.

I think I'm doing the same thing as suggested here ([How to use enum within a struct in ANSI C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344721/how-to-use-enum-within-a-struct-in-ansi-c)), but I can't stop getting random errors.

EDIT: For some reason in Visual Studio when I type asd. the usual dropdown box comes up, but there's an option for 'Typedata' as well as 'SERIE' and 'FILM'. Personally I think there's something wrong with the declaration of the struct, but it was given, and I'm not supposed to edit it.

EDIT EDIT: I'm creating a C++ project in Visual Studio 2008, but every source file is either .h or .c.  This is what we've been taught as 'C', but I'm starting to wonder how true that actually is.

Answer (score 5):

It seems, by the errors messages, that you are actually not having a C program, but a C++ program. For that you have to use the scoping operator `::`  as in

```
asd.programmaType = Programma::SERIE;
```

Comment: Yeah, we were told to create C++ programs in visual studio, but naming the files something.c

This actually works, and now I'm confused as hell :p

Comment: @JelcoAdamczyk The VC++ compiler doesn't really have a "proper" C frontend, and basically compiles all files in C++ mode.

Comment: No this sounds like actual C.

Comment: Actually, I didn't try compiling when VS gave me the errors, it compiles just fine even though VS says it won't. I suppose the environment is C++, and the compiler is C?

Comment: @JelcoAdamczyk: if you want to test your code with a C compiler, you might find it useful to install eclipse and MinGW gcc.

Comment: eclipse is not very useful for C langage, try gvim on windows. Even better, run gcc on linux!

Comment: @JelcoAdamczyk The errors in your question, is those when you hover over the lines in the editor, and the have red squiggly lines under them? Then it's might be because the MSVC parser is not the same one used by the editor.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming C, you're declaring a struct (without a typedef) incorrectly.

Try:

```
struct Programma asd;
```

Comment: I typedef'd it in the header file, and other values do work (asd.titel = "asd" for example)

Comment: Ok. What you have would compile in C fine, but not C++.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
Programma asd;
```

by

```
struct Programma asd;
```

then `asd.programmaType = SERIE;` should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
asd.programmaType = Programma::SERIE;
```